# Unable to set tablet display mode to HDMI

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, hdmi

I'm new to android and trying to connect my tablet to LCD TV using a HDMI connector. The instructions in the manual are as below:

1. Set the TV mode to HDMI.
2. Connected the HDMI cable between tablet and TV's respective ports.
3. **Set the tablet display mode under Display Settings to HDMI.**

Steps 1 and 2 went good, but in Step 3 I'm unable to find any option in Settings and Display Settings as HDMI. However my default video player named Vortex player has an option to "Play on TV" where the display can be set to HDMI and the video plays fine on the TV.

This leaves me to think that both the TV and HDMI cable are working fine but I suspect that the tablet's firmware might be that of a different model perhaps which does not support HDMI (wild guess).

The tech support suggested to download and install the latest "software" (not sure if it's a firmware or not, even they were not..) to help fix the issue with steps by connecting it to PC through USB with a bunch of steps. But this software which shows prompts in chinese doesn't seem to help the cause either. Tech support also says I should be prompted to select display mode on tablet when connected to HDMI but it didn't happen either.

Details of my tab as below:

- Name: Penta T-Pad IS703C ([T-Pad IS703C With BSNL](http://www.pantel.in/tablet/t-pad-is703c-37.html))
- Manufacturer: Pantel
- Android: 4.0.3
- Kernel: 3.0.8
- Build Number: fj_vortex-userdebug 4.0.3 IML74K
  eng.zjd1.20120413.113558 test-keys

Request thoughts and suggestions on the same that could help me fix the situation.

P.S the above information remained unchanged even after the "software update", so I suspect that it might've done nothing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching on the net and string of emails with the customer care I received a call from a member claiming to be from the technical team. The end result of the call was that there is no HDMI setting in the settings panel and the only way to display content on to the TV using HDMI is through the stock "Vortex" player, which basically has no options than to change volume, display mode and the tracker. I couldn't find any info on this player's version or if there's any update for it that could help. Also my search for some effective alternative like [RealHDMI](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmanapps.realhdmi&hl=en) for DroidX almost has hit a dead end. Marking this as answered to serve as information source for people who buy this product and hope I might receive some effective alternatives in the future.